# Desktop applications fail to open web pages

Tags: firefox

I have several Firefox profiles. Most of the time, I'm using my default Firefox profile, and it is always open. I start each profile from shortcuts in the format below:

```
"<FirefoxExecutablePath>\firefox.exe" -no-remote -p "<ProfileName>"
```

My problem is, when a desktop application tries to open a web page, I get the error message below:

[image]

```
[Close Firefox]
Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.
[OK]
```

I want web pages from desktop applications to open in new tabs in the default Firefox profile.

How do I do this?

(Version: Firefox 21.0 and 22.0)

Answer (score 1):

In [one of the support pages of Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_in_use), there is a warning that `-no-remote` should never be using when starting default profiles.

> You can also get this message if you try to open a link from an external program (e.g., double-click a link in an email or HTML file) and there is another instance running that uses the default profile and that was started with the -no-remote argument (or you have the environment variable `MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1` set). You should never use -no-remote to start the "default" profile. See Opening a new instance of your Mozilla application with another profile for more information.

And there is [another explanation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_your_Mozilla_application_with_another_profile) for this issue:

> Important: Never use -no-remote to start the "default" profile (the one that is set to open without asking when you launch Firefox). That's because when you launch Firefox, for example, by clicking a link in your mail program, you will get a Firefox is already running but is not responding message if the default profile is already in use. The solution is to always start the default profile normally and launch all others with -no-remote. Then it will work.